# Notched BottomAppBar Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am just getting started with flutter and I want to create a bottom appbar with a FAB and a notch.

My Scaffold code is the following:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        notchMargin: 2.0,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.cancel), title: Text("Title")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.cancel), title: Text("Title")),
        ]),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
```

However, this code doesn't show the notch. It does align the FAB and shows the elements in the app bar, but there is no notch.

Comment: could you add an image about you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran your code(with some fixes) and it works at my end. You might want to use a bigger notch margin to see the effect.

Also a screenshot helps when asking UI questions.

Here is a screenshot from my simulator [Screenshot showing notch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhqtt.png)